# Marker color in legend

Tags: pgfplots, color, legend

Since I updated to TexLive2012 yesterday, I can't get ant colored markers in my legend. Where as first I could put the following in the `\addlegendentry` options, it now won't work. `[{draw=blue,fill=blue!30!white}]`
Now it will make a box around my text with the color described. Do I create the legend in a wrong way or is something else going wrong?

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[title=\textit{ D - $VMG_{up}$}, xlabel=\textit{$VMG_{up}$ [kn]}, ylabel=\textit{D [m]}, legend style={cells={anchor=west},legend pos=outer north east},minor tick num=1]

\addplot[scatter,only marks, mark=*,mark size=1.5,scatter/use mapped color=
{draw=blue,fill=blue!30!white}]coordinates{
(1.9,   5.4)
(2.1,   5.75)
(2.5,   6.14)
(1.95,  5.6)
(2,     5.28)
(2.1,   5.4)
(1.9,   4.89)
(2.19,  4.94)
(2.36,  5.3)
};

\addlegendentry{$C_n$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've only put in a few coordinates. Normally I'm importing them from a `.dat` file.

Also I am not an experienced user, so it may be just a silly question.

Comment: Welcome here! Something which does no longer work after an update is never a "silly question"... do you have any compiled TeX files which have been compiled with your old installation? The `.log` file contains the version number of `pgfplots`. And: could you provide the version number of `pgfplots` after the update (also in the `.log` file, search for the first occurrence of `pgfplots`)

Comment: The log file says I am using 'pgfplots 2011/12/29 v1.5.1'. Previoudly it was the 1.3 version. Should delete every file except the .tex and compile again?

Answer (score 3):

I found the commit which caused the regression. However, I have the vague impression that the current behavior is the one which matches the documentation (which claims that options after `\addlegendentry[...]` apply to the TEXT, not to the image). In other words: it might have been a bug that it affected the image at all...

I will think about it.

In the meantime, I think that you would benefit from the following course of action:

1. do not use `scatter` plots if all your plot marks look the same. The `scatter` plot is a special "Scatter plot", namely one in which each mark has its individual look (like a color). The `only marks` style is completely sufficient for your needs.
2. use `mark options={draw=blue,fill=blue!30!white}` instead of `scatter/use mapped color`. The `mark options` are applied anyway, and they will be communicated to legend automatically.